# Nested menu in Typo3

Tags: navigation, typo3, typoscript, fluid

I want to create a mixed menu (horizontal & vertical) that replicates the structure of my site.

Assuming my page structure in Typo3 looks like this:

```
<root>
-FIRST
--child
--child
--child
-SECOND
--child
--child
--child
-THIRD
--child
--child
--child
```

The menu would then look like this:

```
FIRST    SECOND    THIRD 
child    child     child
child    child     child
child    child     child
```

In my previous version, the parent pages where static and I used a TypoScript to create menus for the children. Since I didn't know better, each of the displayed menus had its own code looking something like this:

```
lib.menuChildren = HMENU
lib.menuChildrenl{
  special = directory
  special.value = {$nav.first}
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      ATagTitle.field = title
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    CUR < .ACT
    CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1
  }
}
```

This is the Fluid template rendering the menu:

```
<ul class="nav nav-default">
  <li>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
      <li class="nav-caption">FIRST</li>
      <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.childrenFirst" />
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
      <li class="nav-caption">SECOND</li>
      <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.childrenSecond" />
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
      <li class="nav-caption">THIRD</li>
      <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.childrenThird" />
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

To avoid the hardcoded parents, I'd like to create the entire menu dynamically. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your HMENU at the root level and add a depth to your HMENU (2 = TMENU). Something like this (adjust the HTML as you like):

```
lib.menuChildren = HMENU
lib.menuChildrenl{
  special = directory
  special.value = {$root}
  wrap = <ul class="nav nav-default">|</ul>
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    expAll = 1
    NO = 1
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
      ATagTitle.field = title
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
    CUR < .ACT
    CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1
  }
  2 < .1
  2.wrap = <ul class="nav nav-stacked">|</ul>
}
```

To make the appearance vertical/horizontal you have to use CSS.

http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Index.html

Comment: When removing the typo in line 2, it works except for two little details. 1.) the parents are outside the `nav-stacked` wrap and 2.) they don't have the class `nav-caption` assigned (as in my HTML snippet)

Comment: Also, the entire vertical "block" of links will be wrapped inside the class `active`, not just the link

Comment: Play around a little bit with the configuration. In the above Typoscript, we say: "Handle all pages in the active rootline (ACT) the same like the current active page (CUR) and do this for both depths (2 < .1)". You can alter the behavior like you wish. I recommend the trial and error principle from here out, so you can understand how this HMENU works. I also added a lin to the offical documentation where you can find every component explained as well as examples.

Comment: I came to stackoverflow *after* giving the documentation a try. Anyway, I solved the active state, but I have no clue how to treat the parent items differently from the rest. I tried to solve it using CSS, but then I'd still have a problem on IE8, so I'd really prefer adding a class to parent items.